# Monitoring Files with dynamic file name

Tags: perl, monitoring

How to monitor a text file  where the  name of the file changes every day.
Ex.   1st Day:  Test-2012-12-15.txt
                   2nd Day:  Test-2012-12-16.txt

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. This question cannot be answered as it stands - you need to give us a bit more detail. At the very least - what you mean by 'monitor' and what you actually do with the file. Some sample code is generally good too.

Answer (score 0):

Use Time::Piece, which has been a core module since perl 5.9.5

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $today = localtime;
my $file = "Test-" . $today->ymd() . ".txt";

# $file = Test-2015-02-06.txt
```

If you don't want to create an interim `$today` variable you can also do: -

```
my $file = "Test-" . (localtime)->ymd() . ".txt";
```

Refer to the [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.29/Piece.pm) documentation on CPAN for more information.